# one cellphone is working while other is interrupted. WIFI issue

Tags: wireless-networking

have a dsl modem. It is around 8 years now i use. In my country we have net restrictions but i dont think the issue related to it. So basically my laptop and my phone in some days disconnects from net and connects again. Sometimes it is quick sometimes takes time. Sometimes the internet wifi name even is disappeared and you should wait until appearance or anyway turnoff modem and wait one minute and turn on. It is really annoying. **The strange thing is another cell phone has no problem with wifi!** **One of the cell phones in house works properly no issue with one of the cellphone.** . it was not like my cellphone and my laptop. Also, PC which is directly connected to cable had no problem. The lights seems ok in modem. However when i shake modem the lights are turned off! We sometimes use vpn due to restrictions. How come one cellphone has bot the same experience as our and the cable net pc works ok?

This is really annoying could anybody help me. Is it related to cell phone laptop or modem router or what

Comment: *"when i shake modem the lights are turned off!"* Sounds like time for a new modem, or at least check the power connectors on that one.

Comment: But if that is the problem why one of the cell phone is working properly?

Comment: I think it's related to the cell phone and the modem but let me ask first is that cell phone works fine in others WIFI ( Work, friends )?

Comment: Does this happen when both phones are near the modem? Do they use the same frequency (2.4/5 GHz)?

Comment: @ harrymc Hello. How can I know the frequency? No, one of them far from modem but still we have three actually. one of them works always. Two lose internet sometimes some days! Hoq about laptop frequency?

Comment: @guest777 I am not sure my friend I never tried that other places. However, my laptop near modem has interrupted connection sometimes! My cellphone also But another cellphone works well.

Comment: When you say modem, why when I attach cable to modem and then to pc it works very well. You mean by modem modem wifi?

Comment: my phone in some days disconnects from net and connects again.   ...  Maybe delete the wireless profile, restart the phone and set it up again.

Comment: @ john can you let me know how can I do that?

Comment: If  you mean forget ...no that does not solve

Comment: When you forget the profile, it is deleted.  Forget it , restart the phone and make a new connection. That often works

Comment: Thsnks. No it is not.