# Connection directly to the modem

Tags: wireless-networking

My laptop shows wifi connection. I want to connect cable to the modem and plug into laptop to use directly from the modem since my wifi is not working well. What should I do? Whenever I plug the modem to laptop nothing happened

Comment: How and where are you plugging the ethernet cable? What are the models of your computer and modem? Why do you think it's not working?

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** Your modem has an external IP address from the ISP.

You need to connect an Ethernet Cable from the computer to a LAN port on the modem.

If there is no Internet connection, then give the computer a static IP on the modem.

Network Properties, change adapter settings, select your adapter.

Look for TCP/IP V4 in the list and select Properties of TCP/IP V4.

[image: Windows Static IP Setup]

You need the IP address and DNS address.  Ask your ISP for these numbers.

**(2)** Ultimately, it may be easier for you to get an inexpensive wired router, set it up and plug your computer into a LAN port of the router and get DHCP.

Check with your ISP:  Your modem may have a router built in and you can use that.  Ask them what LAN port.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea   https://superuser.com/questions/1765704/one-cellphone-is-working-while-other-is-interrupted-wifi-issue?noredirect=1#comment2747424_1765704